# File Not Found - Nginx in Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

## Description

I have a docker container with this

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

---

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '2'
services:

  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 85:80

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
        - "33062:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

---

The docker seems to build and start successfully

```
docker-compose up -d
docker_app_1 is up-to-date
docker_database_1 is up-to-date
Recreating docker_web_1 ... 
Recreating docker_web_1 ... done
```

but I kept getting

> File not found.

How would one go about debugging this?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your docker-compose file?

Comment: @Sergiu : as requested, I include my **docker-compose.yaml** in the post.

Comment: @kyo did you got any solution for this?, i m also getting the similar error

Answer (score 2):

All **volumes** and other directory settings ideally point to the same location. In your nginx.conf you have     root /var/www/public; but in your yal you use /var/www. That might be you problem.

As for steps to proceed, you can check what directories your service actually uses by using the command the following command after you spin up your docker-compose.yml file :
`docker-compose exec yourServiceName sh`

replace yourServiceName with any service you have defined in your yaml. So *app* , *web* or *database*  in your yaml above. And that command will take you into the shell (sh) of the container speicified. You can also replace *sh* with other commands to perform other actions with your container.

Answer (score 1):

start your container with docker exec -it xxxxxx bash

once you do that you will be inside the container. Now check your files if they are at the location you are putting them according to your docker-compose file.

Comment: what is xxxxxx ? Is it some kind of docker id ? or pid ?

Comment: Using ‘docker ps’ or ‘docker ps -a’ will result in a list of docker containers. Look for the ID of your container. xxxxxx is the container id. => 'docker exec -it <container-id> bash'